# Writing with RegCreateKeyEx to windows 8 hklm registry location

Tags: c++, windows, windows-8, wix, registry

While calling:

```
::RegCreateKeyEx( HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
                "SOFTWARE\\xxx\yyy,
                0,
                NULL,
                REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE,
                KEY_ALL_ACCESS,
                NULL,
                &hKey,
                &dwDisposition)
```

Error 5 ("Access Denied) is returned. This is only happening on windows 8. On windows 7 and all others I am successfully writing to this place. I tried to put  KEY_WOW64_32KEY|REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE but I am getting error 57 then.

I can not say to my user to make my application run as admin. Is there any other way to get access to read/write to this location?

EDIT: Uac is turned off.  How can my installer create the key so that it is accessible from a non-elevated program. I am using wix for making installer.

Comment: This is normal, you cannot access HKLM unless your program runs elevated.  You'll need to provide a manifest to enable the UAC prompt or have your installer create the key so that it is accessible from a non-elevated program.  Use HKCU instead.

Comment: If you can't follow Hans advice, you will need to save your options elsewhere. Look at Environment::GetFolderPath() and Environment::SpecialFolders -- There are special folders for lots of different purposes. The ones I usually use are CommonApplicationData (shared application config), Personal (for user docs), and ApplicationData (for user settings)